# Spring MVC resources mapping tag not working on server host

Tags: spring-mvc, ubuntu, tomcat

Hello there I am still a beginner in Spring so go easy on me, please.

I developed web application using `SpringMVC` and I used in my `servlet-context.xml` resources mapping to store my photos in a specific folder like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/**"
               location="file:///var/lib/tomcat7/photos/  "/>
```

And it worked fine on my local machine, however after I deployed my application on my server host and changed the path to fit in on my server the application can no longer find the path.
What should I do to solve such a problem?

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, please include in your question.  Ensure the user the app is running as has access to the folder.

Comment: I made sure of the file permission and there's nothing in the logs...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried (i.e. retrieve a file?) and what you have in that folder?

Comment: <img src="/photos/1.png"/>
(404 NOT FOUND)

Comment: and `file:///var/lib/tomcat7/photos/1.png` exists?  all folders are lower case?  if so, try debugging into spring and seeing where on the file system it's actually looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parent directory has no permissions but the child has.
So i had to give all the directory path a permission to write on it.